# Behind the scene Send Http request

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using ionic framework, i want to fetch all details of current user. I have a large amount of data. 
I want to show progress bar on header and need to show counter (Remaining data) like downloading 1/100 and so on.

Can we run this on behind the scene and how we show.

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show a basic progress bar - there are several implementations available for angular, which show some **ramdom** progress.

In Angular it's yet not possible to show the **real** progress with the actual numbers. You need to implement a [XHR `progress` handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest), but this is not (yet) supported by angular.

You have to patch angular or implement your own request handler. For more information see the [discussion thread](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1934).

Comment: +1 ! I use the not bad [Angular Load Bar](https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-loading-bar) which bring a good synthax and some documentation. But like you said, most is fake ;)